# テキストファイルをJavaScriptで読み込む

Tags: javascript

どのサイトを調べてもinputを用いたファイルのロードしか乗っていません

ロード時に同じサーバー上にあるテキストファイルを読み込むことはできないのでしょうか

サーバーサイドで動くJavascriptを想定しています

Comment: サーバサイドとクライアントサイド、どちらで動くJavascriptを想定していますか？

Comment: サーバーサイドを想定しています

Answer (score 3):

サーバサイドということで、Node.jsのFSモジュールを利用するのが標準的かと存じます。

[File System | Node.js v11.9.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

また、1行ずつ読み込む例も掲載されています。

[Example: Read File Stream Line-by-Line](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line)